# Android: Cast View to View

Tags: android

I have a class that extends View (MyView extends View)

In Activity I have next:

```
    View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_view);

    //here I have error because of cast
    MyView myView = view;
```

Why its asked me to add cast ?

P.S: I added cast and app is crashes.

Comment: have u added anything  in xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way
Just add in xml like

```
<YourPackage Name.MyView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/myview"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>   
</YourPackage Name.MyView>
```

and after that use in activity as given below

```
   MyView view = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_view);
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyView` is a `View`, but `View` is not necessarily a `MyView`, so you need to explicitly cast it.

If it crashes, it means that the view with the ID `relative_layout_view` is NOT of type `MyView`, you need to make sure what its type is in the layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
MyView view = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is that you are down casting your `view` instance to `MyView`.

its not always safe to down cast any object to its subclass and that is why compiler forces programmer to explicitly typecast his object to subclass.

In your case, `view` is not of type `MyView`. and this is the reason compiler gives `classCastException`.

But if `R.id.relative_layout_view` was of type MyWiew, it would have not generated any exception.